# Eclipse CDT error in subdir.mk

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I try for the first time to use Eclipse for a C++ project. I currently have an error in one of the subfolder makefile generated automatically by eclipse (subdir.mk). Here is the complete file:

```
# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
CPP_SRCS += \
../src/model_bis/Instance.cpp \
../src/model_bis/ThreeIndexFormulation.cpp 

OBJS += \
./src/model_bis/Instance.o \
./src/model_bis/ThreeIndexFormulation.o 

CPP_DEPS += \
./src/model_bis/Instance.d \
./src/model_bis/ThreeIndexFormulation.d 


# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
src/model_bis/%.o: ../src/model_bis/%.cpp
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler'
    g++ -DIL_STD -I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio124/cplex/include -I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio124/concert/include -I/usr/local/include/boost -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" -c "$<"
@echo 'Finished building: $<'
@echo ' '
```

The error appears at the following line:

```
@echo 'Building file: $<'
```

The error message only contains the text of this line without any additional information.

I am particularly confused as eclipse also generated another subfolder makefile which is almost exactly the same (except boost which is not included) and does not generate any error:

```
src/%.o: ../src/%.cpp
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler'
    g++ -DIL_STD -I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio124/cplex/include -I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio124/concert/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" -c "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

I really have no clue how to fix this problem... I tried to rebuild the project but the result is the same. Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem with Eclipse Indigo when rebuilding an old project dating when I was under Debian Wheezy 2 years ago. Now, all my projects lead to the same error when I try to rebuild under Debian Jessie. I have setup a typical project skeleton of mine, and I still get the same error:

Answer (score 1):

After quite a while trying to find a solution to this problem I finally got it... So, I've noticed that this error appeared when I changed a name of a folder... The problem here is that these makefiles or so don't recognize paths with spaces inbetween their names... for example, if in the path of your workspace you have a folder with a space in its name you just need to change it by deleting which spaces you have.

Now you reset your project and the workspace just so the program updates the right path with no spaces in it

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but I had the exact same error, so here goes.

Somewhere in my code I tried copying a queue onto an array:

```
std::copy(queue::front(), queue::back(), array);
```

After scratching my head about the problem you described, I replaced that method with my own while loop:

```
int i = 0;
while(!queue.empty()){
    array[i] = queue.front();
    queue.pop();
    i++
}
```

And the error magically went away. Not sure how that's related but maybe if you have a similar copy line in your code, consider replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of the header files. Make sure you have properly import the header files. Right click on project name->properties-> paths and symbols.